# How to add comma after volume for citation in bst file

Tags: bibliographies, custom-bib, bst

I've created a new bst file using makebst but I want to make one change in it but have no idea how.

The current bst creates references as follows:

[image]

However, I need a comma after the volume number, which is "41" in this case. So it should be

> Polymer Engineering & Science, 41, 1471, 2001.

It seems that I need to modify the `format.vol.num.pages` function but I do not know where and what code to insert to allow this adjustment.

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}
```

I have no knowledge of bst file syntax and if this function is not sufficient information to apply the proper modification, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you still have the .dbj file that the `makebst` utility created along with the .bst file.

Let's assume that the full filenames of the dbj and bst files are `test.dbj` and `test.bst`, respectively.

About halfway down the dbj file, you should find the following code chunk:

```
%VOLUME PUNCTUATION:
%   %: (def) Volume with colon
% volp-sp,%: Volume with colon and space
% volp-semi,%: Volume with semi-colon
  volp-com,%: Volume with comma
% volp-blk,%: Volume with blank
```

Well, this *should* be the code chunk if you had successfully instructed the `makebst` utility to place a comma after the volume number. I suspect, however, that you chose the final option -- "b" for "blank" -- instead of "c" for "comma". If my hunch is correct, I suggest you comment out the last line in the code chunk and uncomment the second-to-last line. The goal should be to mimic the appearance of the screenshot shown above.

Then, save the dbj file and run `pdflatex test.dbj` to recreate `test.bst`.

---

The following uses a file called `test.bst` which I created using the `makebst` utility, where I took care to choose answer `c` ("comma") for the question "Volume Punctuation":

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

%% Create a sample bib file "on the fly"
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{gst:2001,
  author  = "Jayamol George and M. S. Sreekala and Sabu A. Thomas",
  title   = "A review on interface modification and 
             characterization of natural fiber 
             reinforced plastic composites",
  journal = "Polymer Engineering and Science",
  volume  = 41,
  number  = 9,
  pages   = "1471--1485",
  year    = 2001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{test} % <-- newly created bst file

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{gst:2001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I selected the correct one but you were right! This fixed my problem :D